# Can't build Octave from source

Tags: shared-libraries, octave, configure, dynamic-linking, blas

When I try to build Octave from source (to use the OpenBLAS optimized BLAS and LAPACK libraries), I am stuck on the following error from ./configure:

```
checking for sgemm_ in /usr/lib/libopenblas_sandybridgep-r0.2.8.so... yes
checking whether LSAME is called correctly from Fortran... yes
checking whether ISAMAX is called correctly from Fortran... yes
checking whether SDOT is called correctly from Fortran... no
checking whether DDOT is called correctly from Fortran... yes
checking whether CDOTU is called correctly from Fortran... no
checking whether ZDOTU is called correctly from Fortran... no
checking whether the integer size is correct... no
checking for sgemm_ in /usr/lib/libopenblas_sandybridgep-r0.2.8.so... yes
checking whether LSAME is called correctly from Fortran... yes
checking whether ISAMAX is called correctly from Fortran... yes
checking whether SDOT is called correctly from Fortran... no
checking whether DDOT is called correctly from Fortran... yes
checking whether CDOTU is called correctly from Fortran... no
checking whether ZDOTU is called correctly from Fortran... no
checking whether the integer size is correct... no
configure: error: A BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77    compiler settings.
```

EDIT: I managed to fix my problem by moving the OpenBLAS files from /usr/lib to /usr/lib64, though I am not sure why this fixed the problem. Why did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that OpenBLAS was under /usr/lib and not /usr/lib64. This led to dynamic link problems.

Answer (score 2):

As you said I moved the libs from `OpenBLAS` to

```
/usr/lib64
```

and it worked. But I also had to add the argument `--with-blas="-lopenblas"` in order to run

```
./configure
```